# I cannot install Xubuntu from local ISO image through wubi

Tags: linux

I remembered the last time I use wubi, I can install Xubuntu from local ISO image.

and today, when trying to install Xubuntu, wubi trying to download Xubuntu ISO. there is no option to choose local ISO image.

I've tried to put Xubuntu ISO in the same folder as wubi installer, and close internet connection... both not works...

I use unstable wireless internet. It rather impossible to download until finish big size Xubuntu ISO from internet

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566811

It suggests to check whether the installer and the ISO are of the same version - if not, it's not going to work. This is also mentioned in the guide:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Check if that's the case.

Comment: Also, the ISO must have it's original name, as published on the Ubuntu website or FTP server.